# HTML5 video stream in chunks without DASH

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is there a way to control the html5 video stream?
For example:
A video is 1 minute.
A user click play, a chunk of 10 seconds is fetched.
When the chunk reaches to its half (5 seconds) it will fetch the next chunk.
If video is paused, no data should be fetch only as the video progresses.

It can be accomplished with dash.js but it requires the video to be in a specific format and I need to avoid that.

Another way to accomplish that is to use Range header and BLOB but it requires some work and the solution is not smooth and elegant as blobs are immutable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by DASH, HTML5 does not have native support for mpd. Or do you mean you don;'t want to use fmp4? If thats the case, the answer is no.

Comment: Mpeg-dash encoded video + dash.js gets the job done. I want it with simple mp4 if possible

Comment: There are two options, video tag, where you specify an mp4, and the browser does the rest. Or MSE where you feed the browser fragmented mp4 segments (this is how dashjs works). There is nothing in the middle

Comment: Thanks. Can it be done with another video format?